# IPv4 address expects 4 bytes but 1 bytes error when gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.1

I got `IPv4 address expects 4 bytes but 1 bytes` error when I try to `gem install`

Here is my gem env:

- `RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.3.0`
- `RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 551) [i386-mingw32]`

Anyone know how to solved this?

Thanks!

Comment: `gem install` what? Ruby 1.9.3 is way out of date. Perhaps you should use 2.2.0 which is current?

Comment: Can you post the output which is giving you this error? If it is from your own code, please also include the relevant code throwing the error.

Comment: @theTinMan any `gem install` I guess. I tried to `gem install json` and `gem install mysql2`. I tried to use 2.1.5 but the problem persist.

Comment: @JumpandSpintoWin the error message is `IPv4 address expects 4 bytes but 1 bytes` I will post the full output (screenshot) when I am back into Windows. No it is not from my code. I do `gem install` from Power Shell.

Comment: Do *NOT* use a screenshot. Search engines can't index them, making the shot useless for anyone else who is searching for a solution to the same problem. Plus they generally are unreadable and include a lot of graphics we don't care about, making them useless for us. Instead, do a copy/paste of the *relevant* text, and paste it into your question (not a comment) and format it so it retains its readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to my Internet connection. The issue resolved once I set APN protocol of my connection to IPv4/IPv6. Previously only IPv4.